# Login website with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am trying to login my University website, but I came across a problem with html unit.

My code :

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_8);
    webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    HtmlPage currentPage = webClient.getPage("http://www.oid.hacettepe.edu.tr/cgi-bin/menuindex.cgi");
    HtmlForm form = currentPage.getForms().get(0);  // forms correct
    System.out.println(form.asXml());
    HtmlTextInput name = form.getInputByName("login");
    HtmlPasswordInput pass = form.getInputByName("passwd");
    name.setValueAttribute("*****");
    pass.setValueAttribute("*****");
    HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("SubmitName");
    HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
    System.out.println(page2.asText());
```

Result :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[input] attributeName=[name] attributeValue=[login]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm.getInputByName(HtmlForm.java:460)
    at hacettepe.Hacettepe.main(Hacettepe.java:34)
Java Result: 1
```

Can you explain what is wrong with my thinking on this problem ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are printing out asXml. Do you see what you expect, in that output?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1nu7FX9m

Comment: Please don't remove the question statement and replace with nonsense, even if the question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Because the element 'login' was not found on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just like user2115021 suggested, as a first step verify that the elements you are looking for are actually in the first page that you requested. In particular, make sure that "login", "psswd" and "SubmitName" are actual values within the "currentPage".

If that doesn't work, try changing the way you get the name of the form. I've used

`final HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("loginform");`

before without any trouble. getForms() might return multiple forms and you would need to be sure that you're looking at the correct form.